# How to get google plus authorised users +1(like) , events and group list or details?

Tags: php, google-plus

I want google plus authorised `users(individual)` `likes(+1)`,`events`, `friends`,and `user` joined google groups  details or list.

I am develop google social connectors in php (magento). I have completed google user authentication.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? I'd love to help but I don't understand the specific data that you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this get activity is similar to facebook page like list 
also u get for perticular activity comment list and +1ed

```
  $optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public', $optParams);
   $activityMarkup = '';

  foreach($activities['items'] as $activity) {
        $comments = $plus->comments->listComments($activity['id'],$optParams);
 foreach($comments['items'] as $comment) {
   print "<br />{$comment['id']}, {$comment['object']['content']}\n"; 
   echo "+1<br />";
   }
 $plusoners = $plus->people->listByActivity($activity['id'], "plusoners", $optParams);
foreach($plusoners['items'] as $person) {
  print "{$person['displayName']} +1'ed the post\n<br />";
}
```